# Django: Fetching Twitter account details after successful Twitter login

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, twitter, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to work on an application where I'd allow users to login using their Twitter account credentials and fetch some data from their Twitter accounts, like the count of their Twitter followers, their Twitter account URL, status count, etc and fill that data into a database. Also, I want to pre-fill certain fields in a form like 'full name', 'twitter url' using the data fetched from the user's Twitter account. I'm using `python-social-auth` to implement the Twitter login mechanism. However, all my application currently does is redirect users back to the form after successfully logging in through Twitter's account.

I'm new to Django, and would really appreciate if someone could give me some leads or links to some reading material or tutorials wherein I can learn how to fetch data from a user's Twitter account, use some of that details to pre-fill certain form fields automatically and store twitter account details into a model. Thanks.

Comment: this really has nothing to do with Django. This is a web scraping question.  You can use Python, but you will have a heck of a time scraping a mostly JSON data site like Twitter.  What I mean is that Twitter is all JavaScript, that info you seek is not in the source but exists in the browser and is created by JavaScript.

Comment: @ChrisHawkes: django-socia-auth is a Django extension to do OAuth authentication against Twitter. After the authentication is performed, Twitter gives you this information over their API.

Comment: @MikkoOhtamaa Any links which I could go through to learn how to fetch a user's twitter account information after using 'django-social-auth' to succesffuly log in?

Comment: @ManasChaturvedi: Sorry, I have not done it myself. But Googling "Twitter API documentation" should set you on the right track?

Comment: @ChrisHawkes, it is not screen scraping, you can use Twitter's API to request these details

Comment: yes but it requires api access, didn't know if that guy has that or not.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to grab some details from django-social-auth, mainly, the `oauth_token` and `oauth_token_secret`. Using those and your application's `consumer_key` and `consumer_secret`, you can perform requests to Twitter's API, as documented here:

https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public

You can also store the `oauth_token` and the `oauth_token_secret` to make requests in the future, until the user revokes permission for your app.

Comment: How do I grab the values of 'oauth_token' and 'oauth_token_secret' from 'python-social-auth' ?

Comment: You will have to check their documentation